# How to specify exactly the last time webViewDidFinishLoad for UIWebView get called?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiwebviewdelegate

I've read the previous post for this question, [UIWebView - How to identify the “last” webViewDidFinishLoad message?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/908367/uiwebview-how-to-identify-the-last-webviewdidfinishload-message) but in fact I didn't get the answer very much.
what I need is to execute a script on the webView but after it finishes its loading completely.
I've tried to count the frames inside the HTML by reading it to a string and then counting them then loading the string I've read to the UIWebView, and counting the times webViewDidFinishLoad gets called but that's didn't work.
so is there a way to accomplish that, or can any body tell me when webViewDidFinishLoad gets called exactly so I can count something and use it instead of the frames.

thank you in advance.

Comment: Counting webViewDidStartLoads and webViewDidFinishLoads didn't work?

Comment: I was using webViewShouldStartLoad instead of webViewDidStartLoad which is get called less than webViewDidFinishLoad so I didn't work with this solution but thank you that solved part of the problem - a big one - but I still need to know when those methods are called (maybe when there is a script, a frame or an image that's what I want to know to solve the whole problem).