# How would I declare this function?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uikit, uiwebview

I'm needing help with this answer from [UIWebView - How to identify the "last" webViewDidFinishLoad message?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/908367/uiwebview-how-to-identify-the-last-webviewdidfinishload-message)

How would I declare webViewLoads_++; and webViewLoads_--; in the following code:

```
- (void)webViewDidStartLoad:(UIWebView *)webView {
  webViewLoads_++;
}


- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView {
  webViewLoads_--;

 if (webViewLoads_ > 0) {
return;
}

 …
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Should be in instance variable of type int:   `int webViewLoads_;`  in the .h file.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way is to declare an `int` in your .m (implementation) file, above `webViewDidStartLoad:`:

`int webViewLoads_ = 0;`

Remember to reset this to 0 when the last load completes:

```
webViewLoads_--;
if (webViewLoads_ > 0)
{
    return;
}
webViewLoads_ = 0;
```

Comment: As a side note, this should also be reset to zero if the user stops the loading process.

Answer (score 0):

You can tell when a webview is really "done" by using the delegate method:

```
webView:didFinishLoadForFrame:
```

Comment: I know this is a noob question but where would I put that? Would I just do this: - (void) didFinishLoadForFrame:(UIWebView *)webView{

Comment: @Alan, That could be the reason why I've never seen that in the iOS Docs. ;-)

Comment: Yep, the UIKit WebView (UIWebView) has only but a subset of what is provided to developers targeting OS X.