# failed to return after waiting 10 seconds although getting a BOOL back

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uiwebview

I'm trying to show a fully loaded webview. I don't want the user to see the webview in the loading process. I'm handling a few webviews at a time and using `webViewDidFinishLoad` makes it a lot more complex for me so I'm trying to do something like this:

```
while(_lastWebView.isLoading)
{
_lastWebView.hidden=YES;
}

_lastWebView.hidden=NO;
```

But I get this msg: 
void SendDelegateMessage(NSInvocation *): delegate () failed to return after waiting 10 seconds. main run loop mode: kCFRunLoopDefaultMode

I don't understand why is entering a loop because `isLoading` returns 0 when the loading is finished.

Comment: You've coded an infinite loop.  (Though to be completely accurate, it's not "infinite", just very, very, very, very long.  Sooner or later something will kill it.)

Comment: (You should never wait in the UI task, and never, never, never use a "spin loop" to wait for something.)

Comment: How should I wait for something then?

Comment: You shouldn't. Instead of waiting to do something, do it when what you're waiting for happens. (In this case, that would probably be in the `webViewDidFinishLoad:` method you mentioned.)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Don't block your UI with that loop.  It will stop the user from doing anything else on the main thread.

Instead, [count the number of requests your webView makes, and make it visible when it's done loading](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2796540/1445366).