# UIWebView method similar to Android`s "webView.canGoBackOrForward()"

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiwebview, browser-history

Is there a way to discover if my instance of `UIWebView` can go back or go forward **n** times? (**Read n > 1**)

In Android I can use

```
int x ; //times I want to test if my webView can go back or forward
if(webview.canGoBackOrForward(x)){
   ...
}
```

Can I do something like that in iOS? I didnt find nothing on the [UIWebView`s Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIWebView_Class/Reference/Reference.html), neither in the web

Edited: If there is no such "official way", any help in how to achieve such similar behavior programming?

Comment: anything that you want to do wtih a certain class in iOS, you will find everything you can do on the developer class references. If it's not there, you probably can't do it. Apple updates them regularly

Answer (score 0):

There is no official way to back X times in iOS

just:

```
 [self.webView canGoBack]
```

Or

```
[self.webView canGoForward]
```

Answer (score 0):

UIWebView does not have that functionality built in but you should be able add to it. 
Subclass your webview and set its delegate to itself. Then implement the delegate method:

```
- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView
```

In this method you want to keep a list of the requests that have been made. From there can you see where the current request object of the UIWebView is in the list of requests made. The request index should help you determine how many times you can go back or forth in history.

Be careful when capturing your list of requests. UIWebView sends this message each time a frame is loaded. Check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/908367/uiwebview-how-to-identify-the-last-webviewdidfinishload-message?rq=1) for making sure you are only storing the **final** request load.