# How to control goback button hide/unhide feature in webview

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiwebview, uiwebviewdelegate

I am using webview to show videos. So when I launch the default site I am going to show YouTube. Here I used go back button also. When I launch the app the page is loading perfectly. Now my issues with app:

1. I want to hide and unhide goback button based on pages I am navigating. (Here I am using webview delegate methods. For the first time those methods are executing. Next time onwards when I click on any video in the list I can able to go through the next page but these methods are not executing. Due to this reason when I reach main screen I can’t control on goback button visibility.)

   **How can I control goback button hide/unhide feature?**
2. Is it possible to **change title of webpage from YouTube to my videos** on iOS?

   If we cannot change the title. Is it possible to move navigation bar along with webview. I am using navigation bar to cover the youtube page title bar.

Comment: If I understand the question correctly, you're looking to implement a back button in a tool bar for your web view similar to the linked [image](http://i.stack.imgur.com/wcDe6.png)? I quickly googled this image and I am not claiming it to be mine.

Comment: Alright, you might do well to look at the `enabled` property for UIBarButtonItems. I did something similar in a web view controller of mine a while back. 

Assuming your controller that is displaying the webview conforms to the UIWebViewDelegate protocol, in the `webViewDidFinishLoad:` method, I would update on each call the `enabled` property of my buttons by setting them to the `canGoBack` property that belongs to the UIWebView class. This was done as follows: `backButton.enabled = webView.canGoBack;`. There is also a `canGoForward` property that might prove helpful as well.

Comment: Hi thanks for your reply. But those delegate methods are executing only once not executes when i move from one page to another page.

Comment: I think I found a solution, take a look at [phopkins answer for a similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/908367/uiwebview-how-to-identify-the-last-webviewdidfinishload-message). I learned something new! Let me know if this solves your problem.